# Electromagnetic entropy maximum in Planck's black-body radiation law

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I am reading Planck's [work](http://users.df.uba.ar/dmitnik/cursoplasma2014/textos/textoPlanck.pdf) on black-body radiation.
In the paper on the page 19 it is said that the expression

$$R_\nu=\frac{\nu^2}{c^2}U\tag1$$

where $R_\nu$ is the intensity of a linearly polarised light,
is an expression of (electromagnetic) entropy maximum.
In other words, it is a stationary state, i.e.

$$dS = 0, \qquad \frac{d^2S}{dU^2} < 0 \,.$$

I don't understand why $(1)$ would be a statement of entropy maximum.
He defines the energy of an oscillator with frequency $\nu$ as

$$U=b\space\nu\space \exp\left(\frac{-a\space\nu}{T}\right)\tag2$$

and the entropy as

$$S=-\frac{U}{a\nu}log\frac{U}{eb \nu};\quad e= 2.71828...\tag3$$

I don't know how prove that $(1)$ $\implies$ $dS=0$.

Also, the entropy function $(3)$ is decreasing as $U$ is increasing; Does that make sense?

I tried differentiating Equation $(3)$ with respect to $U$ twice and got

$$\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial U^2}= -\frac{1}{a\nu U}$$

but I don't know hot to connect it with $(1)$ and obtain $R_\nu$.